# Dependency required to setup activemq leveldb replica store?

Tags: scala, dependencies, activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper, nosuchmethoderror

I have added activemq-all 5.9 to the dependencies

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.activemq" %  "activemq-all" % 5.9
```

but obviously it is not enough... the compilation ended up with an error indicating miss of some linkedin zookeeper dependency. Somebody can help what that is? Thanks!

*EDIT*

I downloaded the activemq 5.9 distributed zip, and figured that I need to add these jars

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.linkedin"                % "org.linkedin.zookeeper-impl" % "1.4.0",
  "org.linkedin"                % "org.linkedin.util-core"      % "1.4.0"  )
```

but I then ended up with this error trying to start the broker

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
at org.apache.activemq.leveldb.util.Log$class.$init$(Log.scala:45)
at org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBStore$.<init>(LevelDBStore.scala:39)
at org.apache.activemq.leveldb.LevelDBStore$.<clinit>(LevelDBStore.scala)
at org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.ElectingLevelDBStore.<init>(ElectingLevelDBStore.scala:96)
at org.apache.activemq.store.leveldb.ReplicatedLevelDBPersistenceAdapter.<init>(ReplicatedLevelDBPersistenceAdapter.java:30)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Scala libraries.

Comment: @TimBish I am actually writing code in Scala 2.10.2. Is that incompatible with the version of Scala lang that replica store is using? If activemq is a scala project (which I will be very surprised about), it should support cross-build to make it able to run on 2.9.x and 2.10.x